# портирование с android на windows-10

Tags: android, uwp, windows-10

Возможно ли не переписывая глобально код, портировать приложение с android на win10?

Comment: В текущем виде на ваш вопрос невозможно дать лаконичный ответ. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, какие технологии используете и что хотите видеть в ответе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто взять и портировать не получится. Придется все переписывать.

Но можно запустить, к примеру, в [BluStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Без "Моста" Astoria просто взять и портировать нельзя.